# Why does the scroll event in JavaScript differ from device to device?

Tags: javascript, android, html, spring, event-handling

I am the developer who is currently working on the project through the `Spring-MVC`. My current problem is not scrolling events depending on the device. My current scroll event code is as follows:

```js
$(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
            push_list(address); // not come in 
            logcheck() // not come in
        }  
    });

});
```

Currently, this scroll event condition function works very well on the `web`. And it works well on the **LG Nexus 5 //Android 6**. However, it does not work on **LGV30//Android8** and **SAMSUNG NOTE8 Android8**...maybe etc. Is that a problem with the `Android` version? Is there a solution to this?

Now this is a function of the `webview screen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by changing the **height** value. This issue is resolved by comparing the height of the `content` with the value of the `top` plus the `height` value, not whether it is equal to the value of the `TOP`.

```js
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollT = $(this).scrollTop();
        var scrollH = $(this).height();                 
        var contentH = $('#pushlist').height(); 
        if ( scrollT + scrollH + 1 >= contentH ) push_list(address);
    });
```